# Footer position overlapping content - definitive way to ensure it is always below?

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I have been asked to have a look at an issue on a site where by the footer position seems to overlap the content.

The CSS for the position is:

```
#jsn-footer {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #acacac;
    padding: 55px 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    clear: both;
}
```

If I alter the margin I can manually clear the content, however this will overlap again if the content becomes large. Is there a definitive way to ensure that it never overlaps the content. I have used clear:both but this does not seem to do anything.

Example URL can be found here

Any suggestions would be most welcome.
Regards
D

Edit:Link removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the `.clr` class that you have set on an element near the bottom of the content. This class is setting the element to a **height** of **0**, thus the footer is being pushed up.

Remove this class (screenshot below):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) Learning new things everyday is brilliant. Edited - this is a component override so my previous comment is void. Apologies.

Comment: @Dtorr1981 - glad it helped :)